# CloudFront + Wordpress で管理画面にログインしようとすると403エラーが発生する

Tags: wordpress

CloudFront + Wordpress で管理画面にログインしようとすると403エラーが発生します。
wp-login.phpは正しく表示されているのですが、ユーザ名、パスワードを入力しログインボタンを押すと403エラーとなり、ログインすることができません。

どのような解決方法があるのでしょうか？
不足している情報などがありましたら、ご指摘願います。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 403 は権限エラーだから理由はいくつも考えられます。対処方法は原因次第ですし、その辺調査できるのはあなただけなのでもっといろいろ調べてもらうしかないです。デプロイの際にファイルの所有者やグループや権限を誤ったってのがもっともありそうな原因ですが、調べてみないと断定できないっス。

Comment: 問題の特定のためにはまずは再現できる手順が必要です。インストールをしてそうなったのであれば詳しいインストール手順。何かしら設定を変更して現象が起こったのであれば、その変更した手順を追記してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

管理画面に入れなくなった経験はいくつかあります。よく真っ白になったりとか昔はありました。
今回は403ということなので、管理画面への接続がサーバーによって遮断されたような感じを受けます。
lolipopサーバーなどは、Wordpressの管理画面へのアクセスはIP制限しています。またさくらサーバーでは海外からのアクセスを制限する設定がデフォルトでされています。
CloudFrontということなのでよくわかりませんが、AmazonであるばWAF設定を確認してみるといいかもしれません。一度ファイアウォールをすべて切ってみて、入れるようになったら、1つずつオンにしていって、原因を突き止める、とか。
また、/wp-admin/にある.htaccessでもIPなどで制限している場合があります。これはsiteguardなどのプラグインで設定したりしますね。一度覗いてみるといいかもしれません。

ちなみに今回は関係ないかもですが、万が一のため。
管理画面でリダイレクトループのエラーが出たときは、たいがいはDBに記載されているURLとアクセスしているURLが違ったりすると起こります。
・SSLのhttpsになっていない
・wwwをつけ忘れた
などです。DBのURLを確認してみるといいと思います。ただ、直に治すのは危険です。バックアップをとったり、シリアライズに気を付けてください。
リダイレクトループの場合はこちらが参考になります。
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175728/redirect-loop-only-for-multisite-network-admin

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決しました！